# ¿Cómo organizar una Table dentro de un modal con Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy estudiando Bootstrap 4 y intento hacer una tabla modal que salen cuando se hace clic en un botón con una tabla para reservar una mesa en un restaurante. Debería verse así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo obtengo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hay dos problemas :

- Todavía no sé cómo colocar secciones
- Todavía no sé como colorear el texto de una manera limpia

El codigo de la pagina esta sobre [Bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKPB3.png) en `index.html` pero aqui esta el codigo si le necesiten. Señalé la línea donde comienza el código modal con un comentarion `Example Modal Button` :

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>    
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reserve a Table</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number of Guests</label>
                        <div class="radio col-sm-10">
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 1 </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 2 </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 3 </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 4 </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 5 </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input name="guests" type="radio" value=""> 6 </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date and Time</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 has-feedback">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 has-feedback">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" placeholder="Time">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time form-control-feedback"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href="#">Reserve</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1 alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <p><strong>Warning:</strong> Please <a href="tel:85212345678" class="alert-link">call</a> us to reserve for more than six guests</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui esta el css :

```
.row-header{
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.row-content {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px ridge;
    min-height:400px;
}

.footer{
    background-color: #D1C4E9;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background: #9575CD ;
    color:floralwhite;
}

address{
    font-size:80%;
    margin:0px;
    color:#0f0f0f;
}

body{
    padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:0;
}

.navbar-inverse {
     background-color: #512DA8;
}

.carousel {
    background:#512DA8;
}
.carousel-item {
  height: 300px;
}
.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}

.tab-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Buenas amigo podrías pasar el `css` para revisarlo saludos

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras Buenas amigo ! Si acabo de anadirlo !

Comment: Que versión  de bootstrap estas usando

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras 4

Comment: Estoy trabajando en una respuesta a tu pregunta. ¿Por favor podrías indicarme si cambiaste el CSS de Bootstrap 4 o es el que trae por defecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te realicé una pregunta en los comentarios, y al no responder, asumo que utilizas el **CSS** de **Bootstrap 4** sin modificar. Tu problema radica en que te falta declarar `.row` a varios `<div>` de tu código, de modo que no se acomoda el contenido de forma correcta. Te recomiendo cheques la [documentación de Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) para que conozcas cada uno de los componentes del framework.

Te dejo el código ya corregido, pon atención en cómo declarar una fila con un `<div class="row"></div>` cada que necesito agrupar contenido horizontalmente en una sola fila. Trate de basarme en la primer captura para realizar el contenido del **modal**.

Sólo faltaría el agregar un **datepicker** y **timepicker** para la reservación, además de agregar cada uno de los íconos relacionados a cada campo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center">
    <br><br><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</button>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reserve a Table</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>    
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                        <h5>Number of Guests</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="1"> 1
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="2"> 2
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="3"> 3
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="4"> 4
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="5"> 5
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="guests" id="guests" value="6"> 6
                          </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                        <h5>Section</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                          <label class="btn btn-success">
                            <input type="radio" name="section" id="section" autocomplete="off"> Non-Smoking
                          </label>
                          <label class="btn btn-danger">
                            <input type="radio" name="section" id="section" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
                          </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                        <h5>Date and time</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">#</span>
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 offset-lg-3 offset-md-3 offset-sm-3 offset-xs-3">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <p><strong>Warning:</strong> Please <a href="tel:85212345678" class="alert-link">call</a> us to reserve for more than six guests</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.D. Ejecuta el snippet en pantalla completa**